# Not able to connect to java 1.3 NamingService using C++ TAO Client

Tags: java, corba, tao

I have been trying to make my C++ TAO (v1.6) client connect to java **`tnameserv`** running on **JDK1.3.**
But the C++ TAO client is not able to resolve the naming service. It is throwing the following exception :

`system exception, ID 'IDL:omg.org/CORBA/UNKNOWN:1.0'

Unknown vendor minor code id (53550000), minor code = 53550004, completed = MAYBE`

This is the debug log I am getting

`TAO (4144|5228) Completed initializing the process-wide service context

TAO (4144|5228) Default ORB services initialization begins

TAO (4144|5228) Default ORB services initialization completed

TAO (4144|5228) We are the default ORB ...

TAO (4144|5228) Initializing the orb-specific services

TAO (4144|5228) Default_Resource_Factory - codeset manager=004AE5C0

TAO (4144|5228) - Codeset_Manager_i::init_ccs, Loaded Codeset translator , ncs = 00010001 tcs = 05010001

TAO (4144|5228) - UTF16_BOM_Translator: forceBE 0

TAO (4144|5228) Loaded default protocol 

TAO (4144|5228) created new ORB <>

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport_Cache_Manager::find_i, no idle transport is available

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport_Cache_Manager::fill_set_i, current_size = 0, cache_maximum = 512

TAO (4144|5228) - IIOP_Connector::begin_connection, to  which should block

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport_Connector::wait_for_connection_completion, going to wait for connection completion on transport[10603568]

TAO (4144|5228) - Leader_Follower[10603568]::wait_for_event, (leader) enter reactor event loop

TAO (4144|5228) - IIOP_Connection_Handler::open, The local addr is <127.0.0.1:54768>

TAO (4144|5228) - IIOP_Connection_Handler::open, IIOP connection to peer <127.0.0.1:2323> on 512

TAO (4144|5228) - Leader_Follower[10603568]::wait_for_event, (leader) exit reactor event loop

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport_Connector::wait_for_connection_completion, transport [512], wait done result = 1

TAO (4144|5228) - IIOP_Connector::make_connection, new connected connection to  on Transport[512]

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport_Cache_Manager::bind_i, Transport[512]; hash 2130708756

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport_Cache_Manager::bind_i, cache size is [1]

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::register_handler

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport_Connector::connect, opening Transport[512] in TAO_CLIENT_ROLE

TAO (4144|5228) - Codeset_Manager_i::set_tcs, No codeset component in profile

TAO (4144|5228) - Muxed_TMS[512]::request_id, <1>

TAO (4144|5228) - Codeset_Manager_i::generate_service_context, using tcs_c = 00010001, tcs_w = 00010109

TAO (4144|5228) - GIOP_Message_Base::dump_msg, send GIOP v1.0 msg, 108 data bytes, my endian, Type Request[1]

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::drain_queue_helper, sending 1 buffers

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::drain_queue_helper, buffer 0/1 has 120 bytes

TAO - Transport[512]::drain_queue_helper (0/120) - HEXDUMP 120 bytes

47 49 4f 50 01 00 01 00  6c 00 00 00 01 00 00 00   GIOP....l.......

01 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00  01 00 4a 00 01 00 01 00   ..........J.....

09 01 01 00 01 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00   ................

4e 61 6d 65 53 65 72 76  69 63 65 00 06 00 00 00   NameService.....

5f 69 73 5f 61 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 28 00 00 00   _is_a.......(...

49 44 4c 3a 6f 6d 67 2e  6f 72 67 2f 43 6f 73 4e   IDL:omg.org/CosN

61 6d 69 6e 67 2f 4e 61  6d 69 6e 67 43 6f 6e 74   aming/NamingCont

65 78 74 3a 31 2e 30 00                            ext:1.0.

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::drain_queue_helper, end of data

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::cleanup_queue, byte_count = 120

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::cleanup_queue, after transfer, bc = 0, all_sent = 1, ml = 0

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::drain_queue_helper, byte_count = 120, head_is_empty = 1

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::drain_queue_i, helper retval = 1

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::make_idle

TAO (4144|5228) - Leader_Follower[512]::wait_for_event, (leader) enter reactor event loop

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::handle_input

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::process_queue_head, 0 enqueued

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::handle_input_parse_data, enter 

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::handle_input_parse_data, read 236 bytes

TAO (4144|5228) - GIOP_Message_Base::dump_msg, recv GIOP v1.0 msg, 224 data bytes, other endian, Type Reply[6]

TAO (4144|5228) - Leader_Follower[512]::wait_for_event, (leader) exit reactor event loop

TAO (4144|5228) - Synch_Twoway_Invocation::handle_system_exception

TAO (4144|5228) - Synch_Twoway_Invocation::handle_system_exception, about to raise

(4144|5228) EXCEPTION, Exception caught:

system exception, ID 'IDL:omg.org/CORBA/UNKNOWN:1.0'

Unknown vendor minor code id (53550000), minor code = 53550004, completed = MAYBE

Destroying ORB <>

TAO (4144|5228) - Connection_Handler[512]::close_connection_eh, purging entry from cache

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::cleanup_queue_i, cleaning up complete queue

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::cleanup_queue_i, discarded 0 messages, 0 bytes

TAO (4144|5228) - Connection_Handler[512]::close_connection_eh, removing from the reactor

TAO (4144|5228) - Connection_Handler[512]::close_connection_eh, cancel all timers

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::cleanup_queue_i, cleaning up complete queue

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::cleanup_queue_i, discarded 0 messages, 0 bytes

TAO (4144|5228) - Connection_Handler[512]::close_connection_eh

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::cleanup_queue_i, cleaning up complete queue

TAO (4144|5228) - Transport[512]::cleanup_queue_i, discarded 0 messages, 0 bytes`

Kindly help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `tnameserv` component is throwing a non-standard `SystemException`. This was always discouraged by the [CORBA spec](http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/vault.htm#CORBA_IIOP):

> Vendors may define non-standard system exceptions, but these
>   exceptions are discouraged because they are non-portable. A
>   non-standard system exception, when passed to an ORB that does not
>   recognize it, shall be presented by that ORB as an UNKNOWN standard
>   system exception. The minor code and completion status from the
>   unrecognized exception shall be preserved in the UNKNOWN exception.

It's hard to tell what that vendor-specific minor code (`53550000`) represents, though. Oracle/Sun doesn't seem to have documentation on their codes, so I'd suggest turning up the logging on your tnameserv to see what it's throwing back to you.

I'd also suggest you write a quick Java 1.3 CORBA client which does the same thing as your C++ TAO client and see if that works. If it does, your TAO C++ client is hitting an interoperability problem. If it doesn't work, you'll at least see the details of the mysterious `SystemException` and it might lead you to the solution.